# Чтение данных после открытия асоциированного к программе файла?

Tags: c++, qt

Как сделать так чтобы после того как я ассоциировал какой нибудь тип файла (скажем .рр) к моей программе и как только я на этот файл нажал и моя программа запустилась, программа могла прочитать данные из файла и использовать их?

Comment: Дам пример: Возьмем Wordдокумент. При нажатии на файл программа Word автоматически запускается и читает оттуда символы. Это то что мне нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Список файлов передается через параметр `argv` функции `main`
Проверяете `argc`(количество параметров) и если оно больше одного(нулевой - это имя программы) открываете переданные файлы.

Comment: Как нужно сделать? Есть ли ссылка?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!